# How to get non working hours in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a lookup table with employees start and end time, so I am required to build a report that show response time as in how much time they take to respond to the client. I have start time of 8h00 and end time of 17h00, it is assumed that between this time there is someone available but if query came in at 17h30 it means the person to attend to it will be available the following day at 8h00. I am trying to get a response time and it should exclude the hours when no one was available and also the weekends should be excluded.

Below is the sample data:

[image]

So my problem comes when the support member takes more than 2 days to respond to a query, assuming it came on Friday and they are not available on weekends, like the one on id 33 which came at 20:28 where no one was available and also id 22 which came at 15:28 but there was no one who was free to attend to it so it was attended the following day.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: What do you mean by response time? How long it took to respond to a query? Do you have time saved for when a query came in and when it was answered? Please be more specific by including more details about your tables (ER diagram) and the expected in- and output.

Comment: You must be tracking more than just start and end times in order to get "response" times. What are the rest of the fields you are using to get this "response" time?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably solve this with a simple case

Assuming that shifts and issue log time are stored as Datetime

```
case
when datepart(HH, LogTime) < datepart(HH,StartTime) then convert(date, LogTime) + convert(time,StartTime)
when datepart(HH, Logtime) >= datepart(HH,EndTime) then convert(date, dateadd(dd,1,LogTime)) + convert(time,StartTime)
else LogTime
end as DateTimeStart
```

Of course, this will not account for weekends, etc, but you can add these in fairly easily.